# v-img load dynamic images raise eror [Vuetify] Image load failed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

In my case, I have two unrelated components. The first component has a button. The second component has `<v-img>` element of the Vuetify framework. The version of Vuetify which I use is `2.2.4`. When the user clicks the button I pass some paraments by `EventBus`. I want to change the image in the second component after that click. For some reason in console I see that error: `[Vuetify] Image load failed`. `eager` property don't work. I also changed `v-img` to `img`. The result is the same. The image doesn't change. How to solve this problem for your opinion?

**The first component** (button click event logic):

```
EventBus.$emit('showLegend', {
    imageName: 'http://domain/logo.png',
    legendVisible: true
})
```

**The second component**:

```
<template>
    <v-img
      eager
      v-if="legendVisible"
      :src="legendURL">
    </v-img>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from '../../services/events.js'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      legendURL: 'http://domain/logo.png',
      legendVisible: true
    }
  },
  created () {
    EventBus.$on('showLegend', data => {
      if (data) {
        this.legendURL = data.imageName
        this.legendVisible = data.legendVisible
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Try to log to the console `data` when clicking the button.

Comment: I already checked the value of the `data`. I see the correct parameters. In my case, I want to update image with the same URL. Сould this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Try to use `v-else` and pass another one with replaced image.

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that the image is bound correctly and displays, but the issue is with the change in URL after the emit via EventBus happened? If it had not worked in the first place, I'd have assumed you might need something related to require. Many times for static images that's the issue. You'd have to write

```
<v-img src="require('http://domain/logo.png')"></v-img>
```

However, I could not get this syntax to work with my own dynamic variables coming from a  v-for="card in cards" myself until I used

```
<v-img  :src="require('@/assets/' + card.imgSrc + '.jpg')"></v-img>
```

which I find rather dissatisfying.